# "Not a tty" error in Alpine-based duplicity image

Tags: amazon-s3, docker, gnupg, alpine-linux, duplicity

This is my first ever question at stackoverflow, so I hope it'll adhere to the community guidelines:

I've build a docker [image](https://github.com/Gymnae/docker-duplicity) based on an already [existing](https://github.com/wernight/docker-duplicity) image which has the sole purpose of running duplicity in an container to backup files and folders to an Amazon S3 bucket in Europe.

Duplicity worked for a couple of days when being run manually inside a container resulting from the image. Now I moved on to run containers via unit files on the host with CoreOS and things don't work anymore - but the command also won't work it I run it manually inside a duplicity container..

The run command:

```
 docker run --rm  --env-file=<my backup env file>.env --name=<container image> -v <cache container>:/home/duplicity/.cache/duplicity -v <docker volume with gpg keys>:/home/duplicity/.gnupg --volumes-from <docker container of interest> gymnae/duplicity
```

the env-file contains the following:

```
PASSPHRASE=<my super secret passphrase>
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<my aws access key id>
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<my aws access key>
SOURCE_PATH=<where does the data come from>
REMOTE_URL=s3://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/<my bucket>
PARAMS_CLEAN="--remove-older-than 3M --force --extra-clean"
ENCRYPT_KEY=<derived from the gpg key>
```

And the `init.sh`, which is called on `docker run`, looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
duplicity \
         --verbosity 8 \
         --s3-use-ia \
         --s3-use-new-style  \
         --s3-use-server-side-encryption \
         --s3-european-buckets \
         --allow-source-mismatch \
         --ssl-no-check-certificate \
         --s3-unencrypted-connection \
         --volsize 150 \
         --gpg-options "--no-tty" \
         --encrypt-key $ENCRYPT_KEY \
         --sign-key $ENCRYPT_KEY \
        $SOURCE_PATH \
        $REMOTE_URL
```

I tried with `-i`, `-it`, `-t` and just `-d` - but the result is always the same:

```
===== Begin GnuPG log =====
gpg: using "<supersecret>" as default secret key for signing
gpg: signing failed: Not a tty
gpg: [stdin]: sign+encrypt failed: Not a tty
===== End GnuPG log =====

GPG error detail: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1532, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1526, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1380, in main
    do_backup(action)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1508, in do_backup
    incremental_backup(sig_chain)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 662, in incremental_backup
    globals.backend)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 425, in write_multivol
    at_end = gpg.GPGWriteFile(tarblock_iter, tdp.name, globals.gpg_profile, globals.volsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/duplicity/gpg.py", line 356, in GPGWriteFile
    file.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/duplicity/gpg.py", line 241, in close
    self.gpg_failed()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/duplicity/gpg.py", line 226, in gpg_failed
    raise GPGError(msg)
GPGError: GPG Failed, see log below:
===== Begin GnuPG log =====
gpg: using "<supersecret>" as default secret key for signing
gpg: signing failed: Not a tty
gpg: [stdin]: sign+encrypt failed: Not a tty
===== End GnuPG log =====
```

This `Not a tty` error while gpg tries to sign is weird.

It didn't seem to be a problem before, or I did some crazy typing on a late night shift that it worked once, but now it just doesn't want to work anymore.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For anyone who struggles from the same problem, I found the answer thanks to the developr of `duply`
https://sourceforge.net/p/ftplicity/bugs/76/#74c5

In short, you need to add `GPG_OPTS='--pinentry-mode loopback'` starting with gpg 2.1 and add `allow-loopback-pinentry` to  `.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`

This brought me much closer to a working setup.

Comment: I was unblocked by adding the `pinentry-mode` long option directly to the `gpg` command itself (didn't need to modify the `*.conf` file).  Before that, I was getting the same "Not a tty" error message.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: In my case setting `pinentry-mode loopback` in `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` fixed the problem